# Reaching Maximum Heart Rate during PE

Tags: heart-rate

I’m 13, and during PE I regularly reach 200+ BPM right after I’m done with what they call our “fitness plan.” I can feel my heart racing, but I’m not lightheaded or anything. My heart rate goes down to a reasonably low level (around 120) within 2-3 minutes of being finished with the 10-minute workout.

I don’t feel like I work out overly hard. I just do as best as I reasonably can without injuring myself (so about 90% of my best).

I’m pretty athletic (but not into sports, I don’t play sports; what I mean by this is I can do around 40 push ups, 120ish curl ups, which is a lot higher than a vast majority of people my age).

**Is this normal?**

Comment: I‘ve flagged this question for mod attention, there is a site “PhysicalFitness.SE” where this would be a better fit. It’s off-topic here.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma Hit refresh and look at it now. It's not off topic at all. It's a cardiology question.

Comment: @CareyGregory I haven’t VTC, but I think that OP would get better answers over at Fitness.SE.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma - Fitness is not a dumping ground for anything that could possibly be exercise. In this case, it would quickly be closed, as we have no idea what would be a normal heart rate without a clinical MHR test.

Comment: @JohnP My apologies if I sounded like that. I’ll probably have a few visits at Fitness.SE to better grasp the concept of this site.